# React Native generate component via text/string

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-native

i am new in programming using React Native. I want to ask is there any best  way to render react native component via string/text?

Example there is string story:

```
var story = "You face the bear please select your action:
[[Choices]]  
[[Choice, Section="1"]] Fight using the sword [[Choice]]
[[Choice, Section="1"]] Use the torch [[Choice]]
[[Choice, Section="2"]] Run Away [[Choice]]
[[Choices]]";
```

Using this string, the generated component is:

```
<Text>You face the bear please select your action</Text>
<View>
    <Button title="Fight using the sword" onPress={() => this.goToSection("1")}/>
    <Button title="Use the torch" onPress={() => this.goToSection("1")}/>
    <Button title="Run Away" onPress={() => this.goToSection("2")}/>
</View>
```

I need the way to convert inputs from user (texts) and automatically generate view from them.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you fixed on the structure of `story`? Making it into an Object/Array would be a lot easier.

Comment: The order of the story component can be different, example: it can be choices, choices then text. However the `[[Choices]] ` tag must be followed by at least one `[[Choice]] ` tag and become `<View><Button>...</Button></View> `. Can you give the example making it into an Object/Array?

Comment: I would have something like: `{ title: 'You face the bear please select your action:', choices: [ { section: 1, title: 'Fight using the sword' }, { section: 2, title: 'Use the torch' } ]` - is this a possibility?

Comment: My requirements is to create custom text editor that is used by user to input story. The custom text editor must be can translate specific tag into React Native Component (like stackoverflow formatting example `This become code`).

If i translate it into the object/array, i think it must be twice work because i must translate string into objects then render the view from the objects. Is there any way easier and have good performance to translate the string into view component? Or there is another way like react native library for text editor but customize-able?